# The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "MyDb" under the current security context

Tags: sql-server, permissions

We're getting this error and nothing we've tried so far has worked:

```
  TRUSTWORTHY ON

  exec sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'sa'
```

sa is mapped to user dbo and dbo is the database owner.  Any help will be greatly appreciated as my Googling skills are at their wits end :)

Comment: Can sa access other dbs in the same server from the same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the TRUSTWORTHY ON in the source DB then we had to run exec sp_changedbowner 'sa' to resolve the issue fully.

For future reference, 'Auto_Fix' does not work for db owners.